# How to change the font of x axis and also how to make bold

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

Can anyone tell me how to change the font of x axis and also tell me how to make bold

```
library(plotly)
    Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
    SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
    LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
    data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)
    p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo') %>%
      add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo') %>%
      layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'stack')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the titlefont family "Arial black" as in python.

```
library(plotly)
Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
p <- plot_ly(x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count', titlefont = list(family = "Arial black"), tickfont = list(family = "Arial black")), 
         xaxis = list(title = 'Animals', titlefont = list(family = "Arial black"), tickfont = list(family = "Arial black")),
         barmode = 'stack')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the font with the `family` argument. There are different arguments for `title` and `ticks`, you might change both arguments depending on the part you want changed.

There is no argument for bold or italic therefore you might need a workaround.
The `ticktext` (HTML for set word between  in bold) will overwrite the text in `textvals`. With `categoryarray` you can define the order of the x-categories.

```
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), 
         barmode = 'stack',
         xaxis = list(#axis title
                      title = "<b>Animals</b>",
                      titlefont = list(family = "Times New Roman"),
                      #axis ticks - names
                      tickfont = list(family = "Times New Roman"),
                      ticktext = paste0("<b>", levels(factor(data$Animals)), "</b>"),
                      tickvals = levels(factor(data$Animals)),
                      #axis ticks - order
                      categoryorder = "array",
                      categoryarray = levels(factor(data$Animals))))
```